# Debugging ASP.Net website and window.onerror

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visual-studio

I have a simple asp.net website.

In JavaScript, I added a handler to the window.onerror event.

When I debug in Visual Studio, their handler seems to override mine.  When any JavaScript error occurs, it enters their debugger and my onerror function never gets called.

Is there anything I can do to make mine still operate without disabling client side debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that client script debugging in Visual Studio is all or nothing. VS hooks JScript in the IE that is launched on debug there are no configurable options in how it handles js errors.

I completely understand your question and why this is a big deal. The only real option for testing your client side error handling is to use venkman, jetbrains (they have a new web centric ide) or some other js debugger.

Not telling you anything you don't already know, just confirming it. ;-)

Let me know how you eventually decide to handle this.